# Path for Chrome's settings search engines file

Tags: google-chrome

On Windows XP the path to the GOogle app data is 
`\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
but I do not know where the settings for search engines are stored. 
The admin locked down the machine from sync-ing my Google account, but I want to keep my search engeines. 
What is the path for the search engines settings?

Answer (score 3):

For Chromium, it is `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Profile 1\Web Data` where

- `%USERPROFILE%` is your home folder, and
- `Profile 1` varies according to the profile you use (by default, it is named `Default`).